# If Radio box is selected, switch between two clicking methods

Tags: java, if-statement

So i have this code here, and it quite literally doesn't work and i just don't know why. It doesn't click, doesn't print out anything. My goal is to make the buttons function as switches between two methods of clicking. Right mouse button clicks, and Left mouse button clicks. Can anyone tell me why this doesn't function?

```
if (rbRightClickRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("RMB Clicker");

            Robot clicker = null;
            try {
                clicker = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            clicker.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK);
            clicker.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK);

            Thread.sleep(delay);

            try {
                clicker = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            clicker.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK);
            clicker.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK);

        } else if (rbRightClickRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("LMB Clicker");

            Robot clicker = null;
            try {
                clicker = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            clicker.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK);
            clicker.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK);

            Thread.sleep(delay);

            try {
                clicker = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            clicker.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK);
            clicker.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK);
```

Comment: _it quite literally doesn't work ... It doesn't click, doesn't print out anything_ I guess, then, that neither of the `if` conditions, in the code in your question, evaluate to **true**. I suggest that you consider posting a [mcve]. Apart from that, the code you posted must run on the _Event Dispatch Thread_ (EDT). Note that you should not call `Thread.sleep()` on the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button to work as a switch between two options, I would rather use checkbox than radiobutton. The main problem your code has right now is the simple fact that you check the same expression in your if statements.

You should either check if the other radiobutton is selected in your else if statement or just assume that if the rbRightClickRadioButton is not selected, then the other one is, and you don't use else if just a simple else.